# ffmpeg smooth transition between frames

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a videos with low framerates (1 to 3). And I want make video 30 fps from it.
I search proper video filter. And this is not motion interpolate, but corresponding pixel to pixel interpolate of two neighboring frames.
Thus I want recieve 29 frames which will be provides smooth transition between frames with ffmpeg.

Comment: Google: avisynth interpolate, or http://forum.doom9.net/tags.php?tag=interpolation FFMpeg can do maybe 0.5% of what avisynth is capable of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter I need is called "framerate". This is very simple and light. With it I can easily make a slideshows.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf framerate='fps=60:interp_start=1:interp_end=254' out.mp4
```